# TextToSpeech feature to read pdf,txt,doc extension files in android

Tags: java, android

TextToSpeech feature in android is capable of speaking the text aloud using this code i can make any sentence to be heard aloud in android

```
TextToSpeech tts= new TextToSpeech(this, this);
int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
tts.speak(**text**, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Here the `text` variable stores the sentence to be heard but the problem is that i dont want just a variable there i want to place an entire pdf or .doc file over there.So that when i click on play button it starts reading the current pdf or (any extension) file aloud with android `TextToSpeech` feature . any tutorial with pdf reading capability would help me alot. please HELP!!